# How to slice children array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

In this example I started by slicing an array. That worked. I then tried to slice an array made with .children and it did not work. How can I get half the children in a example like this one?

```js
var arr = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"];
console.log(arr.slice(4))

var childs = document.getElementById("container").children;
console.log(childs)
console.log(childs.slice(4));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <p>unaffected</p>
  <p>unaffected</p>
  <p>unaffected</p>
  <p>unaffected</p>
  <p>affected</p>
  <p>affected</p>
  <p>affected</p>
  <p>affected</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Dom nodes are NOT arrays, there a collection.. But you can use `Array.from` first.   `var childs = Array.from(document.getElementById("container").children);`

Comment: The result from `children` is `HTMLCollection` not an Array you might want to change it to `HTMLCollection `var childs = Array.from( document.getElementById("container").children )` and the rest should be the same. Also be aware that `Array.from` is not available on IE so you might need a polyfill for that one

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"];
console.log(arr.slice(4))

var childs = Array.from(document.getElementById("container").children);
console.log(childs);
console.log(childs.slice(4));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <p>unaffected</p>
  <p>unaffected</p>
  <p>unaffected</p>
  <p>unaffected</p>
  <p>affected</p>
  <p>affected</p>
  <p>affected</p>
  <p>affected</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`slice` is `Array` method, but it can be used on [Array-like objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like_objects):

```js
console.log( [].slice.call(container.children, 1, 3) )

console.log( [].slice.bind(container.children)(1, 3) )

console.log( [].slice.apply(container.children, [1, 3]) )
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p> 1 </p>
  <p> 2 </p>
  <p> 3 </p>
  <p> 4 </p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove directly as they are Html element

Use this instead or do what Md Johirul Islam suggested

```js
document.getElementById("container").removeChild(childs[4])
```

Comment: That actually removes the element from the DOM, not just the 'array'

Comment: Yes, I understand that. That's why I said do as what Md Johirul Islam suggested or remove it from the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DOM nodes aren't arrays, so if you want to work with them as such you will need to define your own functions to do so. For example, you can define a slice function:

```
function slice(list, start, end) {
    var result = []
    for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
        result.push(list[i])
    }
    return result
}
```

for example,

```
slice(document.getElementById("container").children, 0, 5)
```

In my opinion, such "helper" methods should rarely be created in isolation unless you're absolutely sure you'll be slicing DOM node lists enough that it will save you technical load. For me, these kind of "helper" functions bring with them a cognitive load that really only make sense within a larger framework like Ramda.js, etc. And I mean that insofar as within a framework you are *using* or *developing*.

You can try checking out one of those functional frameworks to see if it makes sense for you. For instance, Ramda.js already has a slice method that will do that will slice DOM nodes or any other array-like objects:

```
R.slice(0, 5, document.getElementById("container").children)
```